# Gradient of dot product

Tags: vectors

I am asked to show using indicial notation that $\mathbf{u}\cdot\nabla \mathbf{u}=\nabla\left(\dfrac{\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{u}}{2}\right)-\mathbf{u}\times\nabla\times\mathbf{u}$. I recognize that this is simply a consequence of the gradient of a dot product identity that is often used.

My attempt at a solution starts with $\mathbf{u}\times(\nabla\times\mathbf{u})$ and reducing this to $u_j\partial_iu_j-u_j\partial_ju_i$ using the identity $\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{klm}=\delta_{il}\delta_{jm}-\delta_{im}\delta_{jl}$. Also, $\mathbf{u}\cdot\nabla\mathbf{u}=u_j\partial_ju_i$, which cancels out the other identical term, so now I'm attempting to show that $u_j\partial_iu_j=\nabla\left(\dfrac{\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{u}}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\partial_iu_ju_j$, however I don't see how this is true. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: "Check my work" style questions are considered off-topic for this site. Can you come up with a more specific question, maybe on a very specific step of the calculation?

Comment: Well I'm reasonably sure of most of the work leading up to the last step, however I am stuck there. Although the equality I desire doesn't seem to be true, so I posted what I did leading up to it in case I have some sort of fundamental misunderstanding of indicial notation.

Comment: while this topic was seen as on topic and answered in this stack, generally, these type of mathematical questions are far better fit for and answered faster at the math stack exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{1}{2}\partial_iu_ju_j$ is more clearly written $\frac{1}{2}\partial_i(u_ju_j)$ which can be evaluated by the chain rule or the product rule. Using the product rule you get $\frac{1}{2}(u_j\partial_iu_j+u_j\partial_iu_j),$ and using the chain rule you get $\frac{1}{2}(2u_j\partial_iu_j).$

And technically you need linearity since you want to do this for every $j$ and add up the results.

$$\frac{1}{2}\partial_i\left(\sum_j u_ju_j\right)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_j\partial_i( u_ju_j)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_j2u_j\partial_iu_j$$

Comment: Ah, I thought it was going to be something like this when I saw the 1/2, but I somehow didn't think to apply the product rule. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: @mfenn Not to rub it in, but you forgot the product rule and the chain rule, either would have saved you.